# How to select multiple parents categories with multiple subcategories in 1 post?

Tags: django

I am creating a blog by Django framework.
In the blog, I have a Post function which I can assign multiple parents categories in that post in the admin page.

However Im struggling to create a model that can assign multiple subcategories under the multiple parents categories in admin page.

for example, I have 2 parents categories(Tom & Mike).
and I have different subcategories under those parents categories.

Tom(**parents category**)
|- This is nice (to Post A)(Subcategory)
|- This is not nice (to Post B)(Subcategory)

Mike(**parents category**)
|- This is cool (to Post A)(**Subcategory**)
|- This is not cool (to Post B)(**Subcategory**)

When the user selects the Parents category e.g. Tom, the user can see subcategories comments to each Post A and B.
e.g.
Localhost:8000/TOM
**Show the post and comments related Category TOM**
Post A - This is cool 
Post B - This is not cool 

the below is the model I created for the Post and Parents category.
Can anyone advise me how to create a Subcategory model what I want?
and am sorry in advance if my question was difficult to understand for you.

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category", related_name="posts")
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Try designing your model something like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',) #enforcing that there can not be two categories under a parent with same slug
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
```

Check out the details of implementing category & sub-category [here](https://djangopy.org/how-to/how-to-implement-categories-in-django/)

Reference & Credits : https://djangopy.org/how-to/how-to-implement-categories-in-django/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this out

Comment: Although I have learned a lot from the link you shared but as the author mentioned, this seems not to be efficient if I have many parents category.